# AngularJS uploading pictures with formdata

Tags: angularjs, multipartform-data

I am trying to post picture as part of formData to my client backend API taking in consideration that the API allow me only to send files as part of form data with no URL to upload the physical file. Below is the code I am using so far, I've also tried some Angular file upload modules ex. Angular file upload but none that I can find to help me to post the file as part of form data (multipart/ form data) as all expect a URL to upload the physical file. Can someone help me please find a way to post pictures / files as form data OR tell me what exactly I am doing wrong in my code below? Thanks

Service method used in posting:

```
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({ method:'POST',
               url:'http://localhost/api/clients.php',
               data: {
                    action: 'updateClient',
                    img: pictureFile
               },
               transformRequest: angular.identity,
               headers: {  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                           'Token': '1234567890'
                        }
             }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                 deferred.resolve(data);
             }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                deferred.reject(status);
             });

       return deferred.promise
```

Form.html

```
<form name="clientForm">
 <fieldset>
   <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="client.name">
   <input type="file" file-model="pictureFile"/>
 </fieldset>
 <button type="submit" ng-click="updateClient(client, pictureFile)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Directive

```
directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Note, you don't need that deferred. $http already returns a promise. You can simply `return $http.get(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) allows you to send form/scope data + file(s).  The code below is from their documentation, make note of the "data" and "file" parameters being used in the $upload.upload() method

```
    //inject angular file upload directives and service.
    angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

    var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
      $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
          var file = $files[i];
          $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'server/upload/url', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
            // method: POST or PUT,
            // headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
            // withCredentials: true,
            data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
            file: file, // or list of files: $files for html5 only
            /* set the file formData name ('Content-Desposition'). Default is 'file' */
            //fileFormDataName: myFile, //or a list of names for multiple files (html5).
            /* customize how data is added to formData. See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for sample code */
            //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){}
          }).progress(function(evt) {
            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            console.log(data);
          });
          //.error(...)
          //.then(success, error, progress); 
          //.xhr(function(xhr){xhr.upload.addEventListener(...)})// access and attach any event listener to XMLHttpRequest.
        }
        /* alternative way of uploading, send the file binary with the file's content-type.
           Could be used to upload files to CouchDB, imgur, etc... html5 FileReader is needed. 
           It could also be used to monitor the progress of a normal http post/put request with large data*/
        // $scope.upload = $upload.http({...})  see 88#issuecomment-31366487 for sample code.
      };
    }];
```